# How do I implement a Countdown Timer Using ReactiveUI?

Tags: wpf, system.reactive, reactiveui

I'm new to the world of reactive and I'm still trying to learn.  To practice, I decided to write a very simple WPF countdown timer application.  Basically, this is what I'm trying to do:

- Have a TextBlock that displays the current remaining time.
- Clicking a Button starts the timer.
- While the timer is running, the Button should be disabled.

I'm trying to implement this using ReactiveUI.  Below is what I have so far...

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ReactiveTimer.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ReactiveTimer"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock FontSize="45" FontWeight="Bold">
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0:00}:{1:00}">
                <Binding Path="RemainingTime.Minutes"/>
                <Binding Path="RemainingTime.Seconds"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>

    <Button Command="{Binding StartCommand}" Content="Start" Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

ViewModel:

```
public interface IMainViewModel
{
    TimeSpan RemainingTime { get; }
    ICommand StartCommand { get; }
}

public class MainViewModel : ReactiveObject, IMainViewModel
{
    const double InitialTimeInSeconds = 10;
    private TimeSpan _remainingTime;
    private ReactiveCommand<object> _startCommand;

    public TimeSpan RemainingTime
    {
        get { return _remainingTime; }
        private set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _remainingTime, value); }
    }

    public ICommand StartCommand => _startCommand;

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        _startCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create();
        _startCommand.Subscribe(_ => Start());
    }

    private void Reset()
    {
        RemainingTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(InitialTimeInSeconds);
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        RemainingTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(InitialTimeInSeconds);
        var timerStream = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
            .TakeWhile(_ => RemainingTime > TimeSpan.Zero)
            .Subscribe(_ => RemainingTime = RemainingTime.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)));
    }
}
```

My questions are:

- Is my implementation of the *timerStream* correct?
- How do I disable the Start button when the timer is running, and re-enable it when the timer stops?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this:

```
public class MainViewModel : ReactiveObject, IMainViewModel
{
    static TimeSpan InitialTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

    ObservableAsPropertyHelper<TimeSpan> _RemainingTime;
    public TimeSpan RemainingTime {
        get { return _remainingTime.Value; }
    }

    ReactiveCommand<TimeSpan> _startCommand;
    public ReactiveCommand<TimeSpan> StartCommand => this._startCommand;

    ObservableAsPropertyHelper<bool> _IsRunning;
    public bool IsRunning {
        get { return this._IsRunning.Value; }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        var canStart = this.WhenAny(x => x.IsRunning, propChanged => !propChanged.Value);
        _startCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncObservable(_ => {
          var startTime = DateTime.Now;

          return Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(20), RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
            .Select(__ => DateTime.Now - startTime)
            .TakeWhile((elapsed) => elapsed < InitialTime)
            .Select((elapsed) => InitialTime - elapsed);
        });

        _startCommand.IsExecuting
            .ToProperty(this, x => x.IsRunning, out _IsRunning);
        _startCommand.StartWith(TimeSpan.Zero)
            .ToProperty(this, x => x.RemainingTime, out _RemainingTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Paul, this is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I was searching on how to use a timer in reactiveui and I landed here. I couldn't make this run. I'm on version 9.14.1 and this is how I modified MainViewModel to make it work.

```
using System;
using System.Reactive;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using ReactiveUI;

namespace TimerExample
{
    public class MainViewModel : ReactiveObject
    {
        public ReactiveCommand<Unit, TimeSpan> StartCommand { get; }

        private TimeSpan _remainingTime;
        public TimeSpan RemainingTime
        {
            get => _remainingTime;
            set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _remainingTime, value);
        }

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            var startTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);

            StartCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromObservable<Unit, TimeSpan>(_ =>
            {
                return Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
                    .Select(x => startTime - TimeSpan.FromSeconds(x))
                    .TakeWhile(x => x >= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0));
            });

            StartCommand
                .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
                .Subscribe(span => RemainingTime = span);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by making the following changes:

1. Added a **vm.IsRunning** flag that gets set to true on Start(), and set back to false when the **timerStream** has completed.
2. Used **ReactiveObject.WhenAny(...)** on the **IsRunning** property and used it as the ReactiveCommand's **canExecute** observable.
3. I've also updated my implementation of the **timerStream** observable.  To make the timer more accurate, I updated it so that it captures **DateTime.Now** at the beginning, then whenever the **Observable.Interval** produces a value, I get DateTime.Now again and subtract the original one from it to get the elapsed time.

Here's my updated ViewModel implementation

```
public class MainViewModel : ReactiveObject, IMainViewModel
{
    const double InitialTimeInSeconds = 5;
    private TimeSpan _remainingTime;
    private ReactiveCommand<object> _startCommand;
    private bool _isRunning = false;

    public TimeSpan RemainingTime
    {
        get { return _remainingTime; }
        private set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _remainingTime, value); }
    }

    public ICommand StartCommand => this._startCommand;

    public bool IsRunning
    {
        get { return this._isRunning; }
        set { this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _isRunning, value); }
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        var canStart = this.WhenAny(x => x.IsRunning, propChanged => !propChanged.Value);
        _startCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create(canStart);
        _startCommand.Subscribe(_ => Start());
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        IsRunning = true;
        var remaining = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(InitialTimeInSeconds);
        var startTime = DateTime.Now;
        var timerStream = Observable
            .Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1))
            .Select(_ => remaining.Subtract(DateTime.Now.Subtract(startTime)))
            .TakeWhile(x => x > TimeSpan.Zero)
            .ObserveOnDispatcher()
            .Subscribe(
                onNext: x => RemainingTime = x, 
                onCompleted: () =>
                {
                    this.RemainingTime = TimeSpan.Zero;
                    this.IsRunning = false;
                });
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** Originally, I wasn't using **ObserveOnDispatcher()** on the timerStream and ran into an issue wherein the Button remained disabled even after the observable has completed.  It took me a while to figure out what was wrong since I wasn't seeing any exceptions.  I only realized the issue when I manually implemented the command myself (instead of using ReactiveCommand).  Doing so threw the UI-thread-access-exception and that made me realize that I needed to do an **ObserveOnDispatcher**.